# Can I get the "total height" of a curve in Blender?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to get the cumulative height difference of a curve, preferably using geometry nodes.
For example, if one curve goes from 0→100m Z in a straight line and another goes from 0→100→0→100 (i.e. twice fom 0→100), just getting the bounding box would in both cases give 100m, but the second curve has a cumulative Z increase of 200m that I would like to get.

How would I go about getting this value?

I am thinking to use resampling of the curve to, say, 1m steps and then check for positive Z changes between all the points, worrying about the curve direction later. I am still trying to wrap my head around how to operate on points and do not know where to start, but I suppose it involves comparing consecutive points somehow.

**Solved: Adding to the [solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/302516/132485) provided by [Chris](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86978/chris)**. I think I reduced it to the bare minimum without messing anything up. It misbehaves if object origin is below the spline of the curve, but otherwise seems to work perfectly.
[image: Node setup from curve geometry to value of cumulative height]
[image: 5m curve objects with different elevation profiles]

Comment: did you try using accumulate field node? it adds up all the values within a group and you can take the total.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Looks like that method was what Chris also used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this node setup?

[image]

of course, depending on your chosen count, your result will be more or less accurate.

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for writing that up! It looks like exactly what I want.
**What is connected to the first math/add node at the far left?**
I have tried to recreate the setup you show but, missing that input, I am unable to recreate the results.


I will go through the node documentation and try to break down the setup so I can understand it, but if you don't mind I'd also be very happy if you could describe the setup. I assume that it is summing the difference in Z value of adjacent points, pair-wise, - but I am currently at a complete loss to understand what is what.

Comment: oh, i am sorry, it is just the index node